# Order dates in a specific format

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of dates in the following format:

```
{
    "User1": {
        "Date": "July 2"
    },
    "User2": {
        "Date": "September 29"
    },
    "User3": {
        "Date": "February 3"
}
```

How can I order the dates by month? I thought of maybe using `datetime` but doesn't that require a year?

`s = datetime.date(1970,7,2)`

I guess if I don't really care about the year and just want to sort off month, I can go about it this way (entering the same year for every entry, right?

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dates.items()` yields `("User1", {"Date": "July 2"})`

Will need to convert the date string to datetime object for sorted to sort the dates. `datetime.strptime(x[1]['Date'], "%B %d")`

sorted would return **tuple of sorted values**, transform back to dict using dict comprehension.

```
print({k:v for k, v in sorted(dates.items(), key = lambda x : datetime.strptime(x[1]['Date'], "%B %d"))})

{'User3': {'Date': 'February 3'}, 'User1': {'Date': 'July 2'}, 'User2': {'Date': 'September 29'}}
```

Comment: I like your answer, it would be great if you could add a little more explanation.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do this using only the month I have a quick and dirty method. But I can't say for sure if this is the best way of doing this.

```
data = {
    "User1": {
        "Date": "July 2"
    },
    "User2": {
        "Date": "September 29"
    },
    "User3": {
        "Date": "February 3"
    }
}


months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

for i in range(1,len(data)+1):
    mth = data[f"User{i}"]["Date"].split(' ')[0]
    index = months.index(mth)
    print(f"User{i}",index)
```

Gives:

```
User1 6
User2 8
User3 1
```

Now you can use this index to do sorting in future..